# Help identifying two connectors

Tags: connector

Hello I'm very new in electronics/electrical field. I want to know what are these connectors called or where can I find reference source for connector type?[image]

[image]

Comment: In the bottom picture are you wanting the unplugged connector or the ones in the back?  The ones in the back are 4 pin Molex Mini Fit Jr (not Molex/ATX as specified below).  I believe the one up front is a variation of the Amp Doublelock Series.  Still looking into the top as well to get you a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

The bottom connector is a **Molex/ATX** connector. Used on ATX motherboards either for power supply (mostly) and/or data transfer. Used in computers extensively, but isn't limited to them; they can be used in a variety of appliances, such as microwave ovens, [older] TV's, Smart Fridges, and newer electric and gas oven/range combos.

The top connector has no real designation from what I can dig up. It's just a normal power/data connector. However, the 40-pin variants were used in old Hard Drives before 2006ish for serial data communication.

For more info about Molex/ATX connectors, click [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molex_connector#Motherboard)